# Stanford CoreNLP: -nthreads flag causes all ner values to be O

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, corenlp-server

I'm trying to figure out why adding the `-nthreads {int}` argument to the Stanford CoreNLP (version `stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09`) causes all tokens to have an output NER value of O (= not a named entity).

As a simple example, create a file called `sample-file.txt` and make its contents say `Samuel Huntington`. Then run:

```
java -Xmx6g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file sample-file.txt -outputFormat json
```

This will generate the expected output, with "Samuel" recognized as a person:

```
{
  "sentences": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "parse": "SENTENCE_SKIPPED_OR_UNPARSABLE",
      "tokens": [
        {
          "index": 1,
          "word": "Samuel",
          "originalText": "Samuel",
          "lemma": "Samuel",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 6,
          "pos": "NNP",
          "ner": "PERSON",
          "before": "",
          "after": " "
        }, ...
```

If you add `-nthreads 8` to the command above, however, the output does not indicate Samuel is a person. Full command:

```
java -Xmx6g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file sample-file.txt -outputFormat json -nthreads 8
```

Which generates:

```
{
  "sentences": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "parse": "SENTENCE_SKIPPED_OR_UNPARSABLE",
      "tokens": [
        {
          "index": 1,
          "word": "Samuel",
          "originalText": "Samuel",
          "lemma": "Samuel",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 6,
          "pos": "NNP",
          "ner": "O",
          "before": "",
          "after": " "
        },
```

For what it's worth, `-nthread {int}` (that is, thread with no s) resolves the problem, so I can just use this command. I'll leave this question here in case others try using the -nthreads flag however.

P.S. Here's my CLASSPATH (obtained from `echo $CLASSPATH`), which contains only the Stanford CoreNLP distribution I downloaded last week: `/Users/dduhaime/Desktop/everett/wiki_facts/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-nthread {int}` instead of `-nthreads {int}` generates the expected NER output.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this command:

```
java -Xmx6g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file sample-file.txt -outputFormat json
```

with sample-file.txt just containing the text "Samuel Huntington" and it found both tokens to be PERSON.

My CLASSPATH contains all the jars in the distribution.

Two things you should start with are re-download the 2015-12-09 distribution (we sometimes make small changes to this before it its finalized) just to make sure you have the latest version and investigate in your Python code what the CLASSPATH is.  Perhaps before running the java command add an "echo $CLASSPATH ; "  Because looking at your java command you aren't setting the CLASSPATH, so it is not totally clear what the CLASSPATH that is being used is.

Comment: Thanks @StanfordNLPHelp! Your command works as expected, but it seems that adding `-nthreads 8` to that command causes the ner tokens for sample-file.txt to both indicate "O". Do you know why that is, or what I can do to get the same output for this elaborated command as I do for your command above? Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: This appears to be a bug with the multi-threading code.  Thanks for pointing this out.